# React JS importing image "Not allowed to load local resource" error

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome

I got a quick question concerning React JS. When I try to import an image I saved in my dev file (so no internet url but a physical path), I get the "not allowed to load local resource error". I searched a little on internet and I found out that giving a relative path to your image load could fix the problem. 
I used to get this error with the physical path and now that I've passed to the relative path I don't any errors but the image does not load. Has anyone experienced this already?

Here's the code for more information:

```
export class LoginPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Image src ='../PhotoStock/Login_Background.jpeg'/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I can't seem to get this image to print on the screen. Any clues? (On chrome browser aka this is why I get this error)

Thanks a lot!

D.

Comment: if you have url-loader alreay, just try to import the image and use it as src inside your <Image> https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-loader

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I ran a npm install --save-dev url-loader and tried my code again importing the  image like this : import Login_Background from '../PhotoStock/Login_Background.jpeg' and then trying to return this: <Image src = {Login_Background}/> (i'm using semantic ui). But the file cannot be located though this is the correct address. Am I missing out on something?